# I am getting this error when i try to access menu

Tags: magento2.2.2, magento2.2.3

> I have Install Magento 2.2 on my local server. but when I
>   try to access URL it gives me this error

[image]

Comment: Does the homepage load?

Comment: If you are using Apache, check if the htaccess  file is exist

Comment: Which server are you using? Or you can check config data table entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by using this .htaccess file.

https://github.com/emizentech/magento2/blob/master/.htaccess.sample